# Check if an attribute is an SqlAlchemy hybrid_property

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have a mixin simmilar to the one below, and I need to differentiate between `normal_relationship` attr and `special` attr.

```
class MyMixin(object):

  @declared_attr
  def normal_relationship(self):
    return relationship(
        "CustomAttributeValue",
        primaryjoin=my_good_join_function,
        backref='{0}_something_else'.format(self.__name__),
        cascade='all, delete-orphan',
    )

  @declared_attr
  def _special_relationship(self):
    return relationship(
        "CustomAttributeValue",
        primaryjoin=my_good_join_function,
        backref='{0}_something'.format(self.__name__),
        cascade='all, delete-orphan',
    )

  @hybrid_property
  def special(self):
    return self._special_relationship

  @special.setter
  def special(self, values):
    self._special_relationship.append(value*2)
```

Because the getter for `special` returns `_special_relationship` which is the same as `normal_relationship` I do not know how to check this difference.

The `getattr(MyMixin, "special")` is the same as `getattr(MyMixin, "_special_relationship")`.

Is there any way, or can I add anything to the special hybrid property with which to check if it has a custom setter.

Basically figuring out which attributes have a special setter defined would be really good.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute of this object, named "descriptor"

```
type(model_attr.descriptor)
>>> <class 'sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property'>
```

So, try this:

```
from sqlqalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
    
model_attr = getattr(MyMixin, "special")
if isinstance(getattr(model_attr, 'descriptor', None), hybrid_property):
    # do your magic
```